# Rails4.2: Seed objects with virtual password attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My goal is to seed an Employee (think User) model that contains virtual attributes for `password` and `password_confirmation`. I'm using sorcery (0.9.1) as my authentication framework and seedbank (0.4.0) to organize the objects.

The error I'm receiving when generating seeds is: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column employees.password does not exist`

Here are some files to show how I have things written up:

**initial_model.rb**

```
create_table :employees do |t|
    .
    .
    .
    t.string    :email
    t.string    :crypted_password,                default: nil
    t.string    :salt,                            default: nil
    t.string    :reset_password_token,            default: nil
    t.datetime  :reset_password_token_expires_at, default: nil
    t.datetime  :reset_password_email_sent_at,    default: nil
    t.datetime  :deleted_at
    t.timestamps                   null: false
end
```

**models/employee.rb**

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!
  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
  acts_as_tenant(:account)
  acts_as_paranoid
  .
  .
  .
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6, allow_nil: true }, if: -> { new_record? || changes["password"] }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: -> { new_record? || changes["password"] }
  .
  .
  .
end
```

**employees.seeds.rb**

```
after :accounts, :admins do
  accounts = Account.all
  accounts.each do |account|
    5.times do
      employee = account.employees.find_or_create_by!(
                                                        avatar: "#{FFaker::Avatar.image}",
                                                        avatar_id: "#{FFaker::IdentificationESCO.id}",
                                                        avatar_filename: "#{FFaker::CheesyLingo.word}_profile_image",
                                                        first_name: "#{FFaker::Name.first_name}",
                                                        last_name:  "#{FFaker::Name.last_name}",
                                                        arrival_date: "#{SeedHelpers.random_date_in_range(1979..2016)}",
                                                        dob: "#{SeedHelpers.random_date_in_range(1939..1998)}",
                                                        gender: "#{FFaker::Gender.sample}",
                                                        email: "#{FFaker::Name.name.tr(" ", "_").downcase}@example.com",
                                                        password: "tester",
                                                        password_confirmation: "tester",
                                                        is_admin: false
                                                      )
      puts "Employee number: #{employee.id} created for Account: #{account.facility_name}"
    end
  end
end
```

The only way I'm able to get my seeds to generate for Employee is to remove the virtual attributes from the hash when finding/creating the employee and removing the password/password_confirmation validations from the model.

I'm curious to know if I am overlooking a way to use the virtual attributes in my seeds without throwing the PG error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that generating an Employee using `#create` instead of `#find_or_create_by!` doesn't trigger the PG error.

I'll leave the question open for a week or so in case someone has more experienced light to shed.

My two cents would be that `find_or_create_by!` is searching for columns that match the virtual attributes. Since it's impossible to find db columns that don't exist in my schema, throws the error at the database level instead of application level due to `find_or_create_by!`'s performance when called.